# What does 'CPU Specific Code' mean?

Tags: asp.net, jit, cil, il

"When the managed code is compiled, the compiler converts the source code into a CPU independent intermediate language (IL) code. A Just in time compiler (JIT) compiles the IL code into native code, which is CPU specific" says here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_introduction.htm

Please explain what 'CPU Specific' refers to.

Comment: I would imagine just what it implies - native code that will run on the CPU of the machine executing the program.

Comment: What about CPU independent then? A few lines up, which apparently IL is.

Comment: This is what makes it portable. It's not tied specifically to a processor architecture until it is JITed into what the processor needs. This is essentially how Java works as well. It's a step between interpreted and compiled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to native code that is specifically for the CPU it is currently running on.

According to [MSFT docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6(v=vs.90).aspx):

> JIT compilation converts MSIL to native code on demand at application run time, when the contents of an assembly are loaded and executed. Because the common language runtime supplies a JIT compiler for each supported CPU architecture, developers can build a set of MSIL assemblies that can be JIT-compiled and run on different computers with different machine architectures